# SQliteDatabase query construction problem in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to build a query in SQLite in Android. Query is very simple and looks like this:

```
SELECT    
        ifnull(object.icon_large, ifnull( object.image, item.IMG_DEF_COVER))   

FROM 
        object , item 
WHERE  
        object.id_item = 1 AND item.id_item = 1;
```

I've tried to use `SQLiteDatabase.query()`, but it can be used only for one table. Any suggestions how to combine queries or how to join them, using **Android SQLiteDatabases query's syntax**?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fox you can use rawquery() instead of query example:

```
SQLiteDatabase mydatabase;
mydatabase.rawquery("select * from a, b where a.id=b.someid", null);
```

or can use querybuilder's setTable() method to specify the joins example

```
 builder.setTables(TABLEA+" LEFT JOIN "+TABLEB+" ON "+TABLEB+"."+KEY_ID+"="+TABLEA+"."+KEY_B_ID);
```

Comment: @Arunmozhi you answer very Nicely keep it Up

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    
    ifnull(object.icon_large, ifnull(object.image, item.IMG_DEF_COVER))   
FROM 
    object 
JOIN
    item
ON
    object.id_item = item.id_item
WHERE  
    object.id_item = 1;
```

[SELECT syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what i need. I need to create using Android SQLiteDatabase query syntax.